# Обработка жестов

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте, помогите пожалуйста имеется activity на ней я создал вкладки, каким образом можно написать обработку жеста перелистывания вкладок при проведении пальцем по экрану смартфона?

**код xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.admin.orshagoes.number_1">
    <TabHost
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost">

        <TabWidget
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@android:id/tabs">
        </TabWidget>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listview1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="510dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom" />

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listview1m"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="510dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom" />
        </FrameLayout>

    </TabHost>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Код java:**

```
package com.example.admin.orshagoes;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class number_1 extends AppCompatActivity {

    String[] arr; //={"Вокзал", "Школа №12"};
    ListView listView1;
    String[] arro;
    ListView listView1m;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_number_1);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        arro = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.names1ob);
        arr = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.names1);

        TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        tabHost.setup();
        TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec;
        tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Вокзал-ул.Соляникова");
        tabSpec.setIndicator("Вокзал-ул.Соляникова");
        tabSpec.setContent(R.id.listview1);
        tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
        tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Ул.Соляникова-Вокзал");
        tabSpec.setIndicator("Ул.Соляникова-Вокзал");
        tabSpec.setContent(R.id.listview1m);
        tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);

        tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new TabHost.OnTabChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabChanged(String s) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),s,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview1);
        listView1m = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview1m);

        // Создаём адаптер ArrayAdapter, чтобы привязать массив к ListView
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arr);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arro);
        // Привяжем массив через адаптер к ListView
        listView1.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView1m.setAdapter(adapter1);

    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == android.R.id.home) {
            finish();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Tab Host устарел  используйте TabLayout+ViewPager

Comment: Ещё бы понять как их использовать...

Comment: У вас случайно нет готовых исходных кодов с использованием?

Comment: У меня есть, но они переусложнены очень. Вам больше подойдёт любой туториал

Comment: Ну ладно, я уже кажется что-то нарыл буду пробовать.

Answer (score 0):

Для свайпов по сторонам обычно используют фрагменты которые помещаются в Tabbed activity.